# Issue with SetContentView()

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I've been following [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xamarin/xamarin_quick_guide.htm) tutorial for Xamarin to make an android application and for some reason the compiler gives this error

```
Error   CS1061  'Resources' does not contain a definition for 'layout' and no accessible extension method 'layout' accepting a first argument of type 'Resources' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  XamarinHelloWorld
```

with this code

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resources.layout.main);
        }
    }
}
```

Yet there is a *layout* folder in *Resources*

Comment: Consider changing title.  SetContentView is unrelated to the issue, which is really about namespacing of resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have a typo in your code.

Instead of :

```
namespace HelloWorld
{
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(**Resources**.layout.main);
    }
  }
}
```

It should be:

```
namespace HelloWorld
{
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(**Resource**.layout.main);
    }
  }
}
```